# Is there a command line or scripting interface for KDE Baloo's file tagging?

Tags: command-line, search, kde, tags

KDE's [Baloo](https://community.kde.org/Baloo) allows to tag files by adding an extended [file system attribute](http://vhanda.in/blog/2014/07/tagging-your-files/) on the file system level (where supported), while keeping a separate index of all the tagged files.  Searching within Dolphin is possible with "`tags:/MyTag`".

Is there a similar way to search for tagged files on the command line or in scripts, maybe with the `baloosearch` command line utility or via a DBUS interface?

Answer (score 4):

A bit late, but maybe this helps:

```
kioclient5 ls tags:/MyTag
```

or

```
baloosearch //?query=tag:MyTag
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `getfattr` & `setfattr` commands.

```
getfattr -d {filename}
```

will give you the tags, like this :

```
$ getfattr -d 20180718_123507.jpeg 
# file: 20180718_123507.jpeg
user.xdg.tags="Vars,Fleur/lys"
```

and

```
setfattr {-n name} [-v value] {filename}
```

will put the given value to the extended file attribute "name". In my example, I wanted to change "Fleur" to "plantes" in the tags, so I typed the command:

```
$ setfattr -v "Vars,plantes/lys" -n user.xdg.tags 20180718_123507.jpeg
```

and it works indeed:

```
$ getfattr -d 20180718_123507.jpeg 
# file: 20180718_123507.jpeg
user.xdg.tags="Vars,plantes/lys"
```

*Note:* the KDE tags structure is hierarchical, so you can have subtags.

*Example:* I give below a bash script allowing to replace tags for all files given on the command line.

```
#!/bin/bash
before=$1
pattern=".*"$1".*"
shift
after=$1
shift
echo Replacing "$before" by "$after" in the tags...
for f in $@ ; do 
    tags=$(getfattr --only-values -d $f)
    if [[ $k =~ $pattern ]] ; then 
        newtags=${tags/$before/$after}
        setfattr -n "user.xdg.tags" -v $newtags $f
        echo $f 
        fi
    done
```

You could also get a look on the [`tagctl`](https://%5Bhttps://gitlab.com/KodyVB/tagctl%5D%5B1%5D) utility.

Comment: While this allows to get or set the attributes, it does not answer the question how to *search* for files with certain attributes.

Comment: Sure. A solution could be assembled combining in a bash script the utilities find, grep, getfattr. It just takes the time to think about and write it...